# Set selected rows of Datagrid in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid, .net-4.0

I have searched and can't seem to find how to do this for multiple rows.

I have a Datagrid whose items source is a Datatable. A user can select multiple rows, do some operations outside the datagrid then click a button to update data. When that happens, I would like the selected rows of the datagrid (prior to button click) to be selected again. That's the part I can't seem to figure out.

I thought I could achive this by storing the currently selected row indexes. I found out they can be accessed through the selected cells, so I tried this:

```
Dim rows As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
For Each cell As DataGridCellInfo In mydatagrid.SelectedCells
     rows.Add(mydatagrid.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item))
Next

 (...code to retrieve data...)

 For Each item As Integer In rows
      mydatagrid.SelectedIndex = item
 Next
```

But SelectedIndex only has a single value, and only the last previously selected line was selected again.

I searched some more and tried storing the selected items themselves, but that didn't work, nothing gets selected:

```
 Dim rows As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)
 rows.AddRange(mydatagrid.SelectedItems)

 (...code to retrieve data...)

 For Each item As Object In rows
        mydatagrid.SelectedItems.Add(item)
 Next
```

I guess I'm missing out on something :(  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. You stored the selected indexes of rows but `DataGrid` wants you to select the items themselves:

```
mydatagrid.SelectedItems.Clear()
For Each item As Integer In rows
    If (item < mydatagrid.Items.Count) Then
        mydatagrid.SelectedItems.Add(mydatagrid.Items.GetItemAt(item))
    End If
Next
```

Similarly, if you want to restore the cell selection, you should store the `DataGridCellInfos` and then use `SelectedCells` collection.